# Removing Tabs in a String

Tags: java, string, tabs, formatting

I need to format this `String`:

```
"public class geo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (true) {
           System.out.print("Yes");
            if (false) {
                System.out.prinln("DSadaDSa");
                x = 4;
                blahblah();
            }
        }
    }
}"
```

to get everything between:

```
"public class geo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}"
```

So in this example the String I want to get is:

```
"if (true) {
    System.out.print("Yes");
    if (false) {
        System.out.prinln("DSadaDSa");
        x = 4;
        blahblah();
    }
}"
```

Currently I am doing it a bit of a messy way by replacing the char sequences I don't want with empty Strings, but the `String` I am left with at the end

```
    "if (true) {
        System.out.print("Yes");
        if (false) {
            System.out.prinln("DSadaDSa");
            x = 4;
            blahblah();
        }
    }"
```

still has the leading tabs on each line.

Is there an easy way to remove these tabs so the `String` is effectively shifted over to the left by one tabs width?

Comment: Why have you done the `if(true)` section? You might as well just leave it out...

Comment: It's just an example method that doesn't make any sense. If you read the question carefully, that code doesn't matter.

Comment: What part is un-understandable? I've said the String I have, I need to get everything in-between a certain sub-string, I've given an example of the output I want and an example of the output I'm getting...

Comment: @SteWoo I don't find input and expect output in your question..yes we are unable to understand your question

Comment: I think people are getting confused as to what is in the code blocks. The code in the code blocks are meant to be strings, not actual code. I am putting code in a string to format it hence why I need to tabs removed. Apologies for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s=what you already have;

//split the string into lines
String[] lines=s.split("\n");

//cut off the beginning of each one
for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
    lines[i]=lines[i].substring(/*1, 2, 4, or 8 depending on tab formatting*/);
return s;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the String class's `trim()` method?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

From the docs:

> ... Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted ...

I believe this will work well for your situation. You can build on what Jakob wrote, but instead of doing `lines[i]=lines[i].substring(/*...*/);` simply do `lines[i] = lines[i].trim();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion croyd but trim() will remove ALL the leading white space, I just want to remove 1 tabs worth to 'shift' the string over to the left a bit